# How do I query an array and delete multiple in TypeORM

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I want to remove multiple options if its question_id is 1 or 2.

The following code gives me this error: QueryFailedError: missing FROM-clause entry for table "option"

How do I solve this problem?

Service.ts:

```
this.QuizQuestionOptionRepository.createQueryBuilder('option')
  .delete()
  .from(QuizQuestionOption)
  .where('option.question_id IN (:...id)', { id: [1, 2] })
  .execute();
```

QuizQuestionOption entity:

```
import { QuizQuestion } from './quizQuestion.entity';
import {
  BeforeUpdate,
  Column,
  Entity,
  JoinColumn,
  ManyToOne,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class QuizQuestionOption {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  title: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  explanation: string;

  @Column()
  is_correct: boolean;

  @JoinColumn({ name: 'question_id' })
  @ManyToOne(() => QuizQuestion)
  question: QuizQuestion;

  @Column({ type: 'timestamp', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' })
  created_at: Date;

  @Column({ type: 'timestamp', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' })
  updated_at: Date;

  @BeforeUpdate()
  updateTimestamp() {
    this.updated_at = new Date();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you need to add a name in createQueryBuilder. Maybe you should try it this way

```
await this.QuizQuestionOptionRepository.createQueryBuilder()
  .delete()
  .from(QuizQuestionOption)
  .where('question_id IN (:...id)', { id: [1, 2] })
  .execute();
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem was with the name & from. I removed both & it worked fine

Comment: nice @HasibulHasan